# How to get result of shell script in webpage using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, shell

I am trying to set up a local server for maintaining local git repositories.

I have already written several shell scripts for a command line utility that returns the output that I want. I would like to run these from the webpage by using javascript if possible. (**Server** will run the script, **NOT** the client)

I didn't write the scripts for the purpose of displaying info on a webpage, but wanted to implement them if possible as to not rewrite the code again.

I have this javascript code:

### test.js

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function test() {
    exec("ssh git@raspberrypi 'ls ~/Git/'",
      function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        // document.write(stdout);
      });
}

test()
```

If I run this with `node test.js`
I get the output of the command printed to console.

> git_folder1.git
>
> git_folder2.git
>
> git_folder3.git

However, If I uncomment the line `document.write(stdout)`, and call it from HTML, I get no output.

### test.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>test()</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I put `document.write("Hello")` before the `exec` "Hello" gets written to the document, but if put at the bottom of the function (or inside), it doesn't.

Am I doing something wrong?
Is there a better way to go about getting the output of a shell script in a webpage?

Comment: You are mixing server and browser execution context. The script either runs on server (1st example) or in the browser (2nd example). If you want to run it on the server and see the output in a browser, you need to capture the output and send it in response. With Node/Express that would be res.locals.scriptOutput = stdout then render it the browser.

Comment: @marekful Thank you! After looking into Express I was able to get this working. I can't thank you enough. If you add this as an answer I will mark it as the solution.